# IE 11 not supporting localStorage alternate for this

Tags: javascript, jquery

IE 11 not supporting localStorage variables can someone suggest alternate for localStorage & cookies. For some features cookies are also not works for me. So i need alternate for cookies & localStorage.setItem/getItem.

To store the values from one page to another page, or between wizards i need this.

Comment: What exactly IE11 doesn't support? Because for sure IE11 supports localStorage

Comment: Check the know issues section of this page http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative for localStorage is [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) or WebSQL ([limited support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage)).

Answer (score 0):

depends on what are you using on background/server side. you can store this informations there. 
try to use Sessions for example.

what is yout backend tecnology?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). It works in IE 11.